# How to know when a property has been updated from it's connected attribute?

Tags: lit-element

Given:

```
@property({type: Boolean, attribute: 'some-attr'}) someAttr = false;
```

I was expecting to see `updated` being fired once `'some-attr'` value gets updated in the DOM.

However, `updated` doesn't get fired at all.

Is my expectation wrong, or should I set things up differently?

Comment: Can you update your question as to how exactly you update the attribute in the DOM? This may very well matter due to how the default value converters work.

Comment: @djlauk [elm](https://elm-lang.org)'s runtime and it's virtual dom implementation is what updates the actual dom in my applications, so.. I can't say for sure, since I haven't looked into its implementation.

Comment: I think you can check with your browser's developer tools. Let me know the HTML attribute when it should be true, and when it should be false. I have a strong suspicion what is going on, but need a bit more evidence.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at Elm's [discussion of properties vs attributes](https://github.com/elm/html/blob/master/properties-vs-attributes.md), the [documentation of the `Html.Attributes` module's `attribute` function](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/html/latest/Html-Attributes#attribute), and the [Elm documentation on custom elements](https://guide.elm-lang.org/interop/custom_elements.html), I am pretty sure, that this is caused by simply binding an elm expression to attribute `some-attr` of the LitElement based custom element. I.e. the *DOM attribute* will always be *present* and hence the corresponding *property* always be `true`.

The [default converter for `Boolean`](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/properties#conversion-type) (activated by providing `type:Boolean` to the decorator) mimicks the behaviour of HTML attributes used as flags (e.g. `disabled` on an `<input>` element): If the attribute is present (no matter the value), the flag is set (`true`). The implementation is really straight forward, if you want to look at it in the sources: https://github.com/Polymer/lit-element/blob/master/src/lib/updating-element.ts#L163

I see these options for your problem:

1. Implement some extra logic in Elm to add / remove the **presence** of the attribute.
2. Create your own attribute converter for the LitElement based custom element.
3. Use another default converter (e.g. for `String`, the "default" default converter) and implement the custom logic inside the LitElement (e.g. using a derived value).

Of these 3 options, I would generally recommend the first one, as your custom element then still behaves naturally, i.e. if `some-attr` should be a flag (boolean attribute), then following which HTML semantics, it should be defined by its presence, not its value. This allows you to re-use it in other projects without surprising other developers.

That being said, there may of course be project-specific requirements, that are more important. E.g. if you only use this custom element in this one project with Elm, your road to success may be faster going for options 2 or 3.

Comment: I appreciate the effort, mister! Please allow me few weeks before I'm able to review your suggestion.